# Why the MVS compiler can convert argument 'myStruct' to 'myStruct &'. And did not file error C2664: cannot convert 'myStruct' to 'myStruct &'

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a class where I use `std::mem_fn` to choose between helper functions.

1. Why my code get compiled and run If I am missing `&` in `m_funcContainer` deceleration ? In the code `&` commented out with `/**/` `myStruct/*&*/`

`std::map < std::string, std::function<void(const myClass*, myStruct/*&*/) >> m_funcContainer`

(but in case of `m_funcContainerInt` the compiler rise compile error)

> error C2664: 'void (int &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'int' to 'int &'

2. I feel that I have not formulate the title of my question in a best way, can you please help me to formulate technically more correct title?

> Why the compiler can convert argument  'myStruct' to 'myStruct &' in
>   std::function

My simplified code is

`myClass.h`

> ```
> #include <memory>
> #include <map>
> #include <functional>
>
> struct ExtraFlag
> {
> };
>
> struct Flag
> {
> };
>
> struct myStruct
> {
>     std::shared_ptr<ExtraFlag>         extraFlag;
>     std::shared_ptr<Flag>              flag;
>
>     explicit myStruct()
>     {
>     }
> };
>
> class myClass
> {
> private:
>     std::map < std::string, std::function<void(const myClass*, myStruct/*&*/) >> m_funcContainer;
>     std::map < std::string, std::function<void(const myClass*, int/*&*/) >> m_funcContainerInt;
>
> private:
>     void funcMyStruct(myStruct& arg1) const;
>     void funcInt(int& arg1) const;
> public:
>     myClass();
> };
> ```

`myClass.cpp`

> ```
> #include "myClass.h"
> myClass::myClass()
> {
>     m_funcContainer["func"] = std::mem_fn(&myClass::funcMyStruct);
>     myStruct myStructInstance;
>     m_funcContainer.at("func")(this, myStructInstance);
>
>     int a;
>     m_funcContainerInt["func"] = std::mem_fn(&myClass::funcInt);
>     m_funcContainerInt.at("func")(this, a);
> }
> void myClass::funcMyStruct(myStruct& arg1) const
> {}
>
> void myClass::funcInt(int& arg1) const
> {}
> ```

**EDITED**
I am compiling on Microsoft visual studio 2013

Comment: I have been looking at this code and if you drop the reference in the `std::map` declaration then this should not compile but for a different reason as the function signatures do not match.  Can you please provide an [mcve] as I am not sure how you are getting the error you are.

Comment: thanks for response. I will create simple example.

Comment: After adding some forward references for missing classes like `MyStruct` g++ 4.9.3/cygwin compiles *only* with the function signatures taking references.

Comment: Same with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3f55eb7152e3821), but it does compile if you remove the reference in `void myStruct::funcMyStruct(myStruct& arg1) const` as well.

Comment: Sorry guys for providing example with errors. So I edited the code in question and put there code from my test project.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have edited code in my question. Should I also post my test project somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that MSVC2013 is not a C++ compiler under its default settings.  It is compiles a language closely related to C++, but with "extensions".  You are being bitten by one of them.

`/Za` will turn off (most?) language extensions, I believe including the one causing you a problem here.

I have heard reports that some headers that ship with MSVC (system headers) can have problems with `/Za`.  And, code that was compiled and tested with `/Za` off could have unexpected behavior changes with `/Za` turned on.  I would include it by default in new files or projects, and if you have an old project activate it and *test* that it doesn't cause problems.

Comment: So you suggest to `Disable Language Extensions`? By default it is `No`

Comment: I have disabled `Disable Language Extensions` putting it `Yes (/Za)` and it got `error C2664: 'void (myStruct &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'myStruct' to 'myStruct &'`

Comment: @TM which, I believe, is the correct error?  As an aside, there is a similar problem with `std::async`, but in the library itself (`/Za` won't fix it), which is why I was cautious above.

Comment: Yes it is an error. I had a typo, missed `&`, and did not got any compile error and spent hours to find my bug.

Comment: So what you will recommend to do with this `Za, /Ze (Disable Language Extensions)` ? is it normal to disable it?

Comment: @Tm I included my advice above.  For a large project, enable it and do extensive testing.  For a small/new project, enable it.  If problems develop, there are sub-flags that might solve your issues.