# What is MVS /Za, /Ze (Disable Language Extensions) Whan I should disable it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What is MVS `/Za, /Ze (Disable Language Extensions)` When I should disable it?
I have read  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) from MSDN but it is still not clear when I should disable it and when to left as default.

P.S.
I had a typo in my code ( I have missed &) and got a bug which cause me hours of debug. I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345509/why-the-compiler-can-convert-argument-mystruct-to-mystruct-in-stdfunctio) and got the answer that the reason why MVS compiler does not rise compile error is `/Za, /Ze (Disable Language Extensions)`.
So I want to clarify and make clear for me what I should do with this option.

Comment: Language Extensions should always be disabled, so that you can change compiler-vendor at a whim

Comment: Every compiler has extensions, the C++ standard is inadequate to create practical programs.  Something as very basic as creating a module is not covered by the standard.  Everybody does it, nobody does it the same way.  Over-reacting to a bug in your code that didn't get a good diagnostic is just a bad idea.